# Retrieve a specific value related to a key from a JSON array

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON array as follows

```
[{"Id": 1,"name":"Test1"}, 
 {"Id": 2,"name":"Test2"},
{"Id": 3,"name":"Test2"}]
```

And I want to get the name of the Id which equals to 2(Id=2) through angularJS. I am a newbie to angularjs.

Comment: `Array#filter` method can be use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

[Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) might be what you need:

```
> arr.find(e => e.Id === 2)

{ Id: 2, name: 'Test2' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```js
var jsonArray = [{"Id": 1,"name":"Test1"}, 
 {"Id": 2,"name":"Test2"},
{"Id": 3,"name":"Test2"}];


var name = Object.keys(jsonArray).find(e => {
if(jsonArray[e].Id == 2)
{
   console.log(jsonArray[e].name);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest but this works

```
function findObjectByKey(array, key, value) {
    console.log(array);
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log("looking for:", i);
        if (array[i] !== undefined && array[i][key] === value) {
            console.log("found at:", i);
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`array` is the array you want to search
`key` would be `'id'` in your case and
`value` woulde  be `2` or whatever you are looking for

it returns the index of the object in the array but can easily be modified to return the name like this:

```
if (array[i] !== undefined && array[i][key] === value) {
            console.log("found at:", i);
            return array[i]['name'];
        }
```

I know there is a more efficient way probably but this is what i first thought of

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have this array:

```
var arr = [{"Id": 1,"name":"Test1"}, 
           {"Id": 2,"name":"Test2"},
           {"Id": 3,"name":"Test2"}];
```

You can always use a forEach through your array:

```
arr.forEach((a) => {if(a.Id == 2) console.log(a.name)});
```

Comment: I tried your method. But I get the following Error. "TypeError: arr.forEach is not a function" @cortereal

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
let userArr = [{"Id": 1,"name":"Test1"}, 
              {"Id": 2,"name":"Test2"},
              {"Id": 3,"name":"Test2"}];

let userId = 2;

let item = userArr.find(e => {
     return e.Id === userId;
});

console.log(item);
```

You can use also Filter [JS Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).